# What does external mean in Dart?

Tags: dart

What does `external` mean in Dart? For example: `external DateTime._now();`

I'm new to Dart, I can't find documentation for `external`, so can you give an example to help explain？

Comment: _"i can't find doucment for `external`"_  http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf  section 9.4

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> 9.4 External Functions
>   An external function is a function whose body is provided separately from its
>   declaration. An external function may be a top-level function (17), a method

The body of the function is defined somewhere else.
As far as I know this is used to fix different implementations for Dart VM in the browser and Dart VM on the Server.

Comment: It is mostly used to abstract implementation details between the Dart VM and dart2js.

Comment: How can I locate the implementation of an external method?

Comment: I am able to locate the file where an external function is implemented by searching the source code for relevant key words. But, it would be much more convenient if I can reach implementations from within an editor.

Answer (score 25):

When we make an external function inside a class like `toString()`

```
external String toString();
```

means this method is abstract and the child of the parent class will add the function body, that's because in Dart we only can make an abstract class.

Summary:

> external function = abstract function in not abstract classes

Comment: Completely untrue. external access has nothing to do with inheritance

Comment: An external function does not even have to be a member of a class in dart

Answer (score 11):

I don't think `external` keyword is meant to be used to mark methods as abstract, even if that's possible

It's enough to leave a method with no implementation to set it abstract, inside an abstract class

It's the equivalent of `declare` in TypeScript, and `extern` in C#, those are used for interoperability with other runtimes, which means you're telling the compiler "Don't worry about this method's implementation, I promise it will exist at runtime", the runtime may be in C or Javascript or whatever

Answer (score 6):

In case, if you are wondering why or where should I even use `external` keyword, here is a one more example for Flutter.

```
class MyStruct extends Struct {
  @Int32()
  external int a;

  @Float()
  external double b;

  external Pointer<Void> c;
}
```

Sometimes, but not often when you play with native libraries, in this case with `Struct` to access native struct's field in memory. Under `Struct` We **must** declare all fields as `external` because it will be external fields from `dart:ffi` (C / C++).

So, `external` is more than just way to declare "abstract method".

Answer (score 5):

> 9.4 External Functions
> An external function is a function whose
> body is provided separately from its
> declaration.

What this does mean is that you define the function, but without implementation. It's exactly how you define the abstract method, but the only difference is that with external you don't implement the method in dart but in C or something else.

Something like String class it can be considered as external functions except that the String class it marked with @pragma('vm:entry-point') which make the entire class use native code.

See the following example to understand:

**This dart's side.**

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/sdk/lib/core/string.dart#L711

**This the implementation in C++.**

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/runtime/lib/string.cc#L473-#L478

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a source for: 

    9.4 External Functions An external function is a function whose body is provided separately from its declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is an equivalent of Java `native` keyword. For example, since current time milliseconds is implemented differently on Android, iOS, Linux etc, `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch` will be linked to different implementations at runtime. So it is not initially known how this method will look like. For this reason it is marked as `external` meaning it is platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Dart language specification draft](https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf#External%20Functions)

> An external function is a function whose body is provided separately from its declaration. An external function may be a top-level function (19), a method (10.2, 10.8), a getter (10.3), a setter (10.4), or a non-redirecting constructor (10.7.1, 10.7.2). External functions are introduced via the built-in identifier external (17.38) followed by the function signature.

> External functions allow us to introduce type information for code that is
> not statically known to the Dart compiler.

> Examples of external functions might be foreign functions (defined in C, or
> Javascript etc.), primitives of the implementation (as defined by the Dart run-time system), or code that was dynamically generated but whose interface is statically known. However, an abstract method is different from an external function, as it has no body.