# What does external keyword mean in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example: this is a private named constructor of `DateTime` class from `date_time` library :

```
external DateTime._now();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a stack overflow post asking the same question:
[What does external mean in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929659/what-does-external-mean-in-dart)

> 9.4 External Functions An external function is a function whose body is provided separately from its declaration. An external function may
> be a top-level function (17), a method
>
> The body of the function is defined somewhere else. As far as I know
> this is used to fix different implementations for Dart VM in the
> browser and Dart VM on the Server.

-Günter Zöchbauer