# Dart how can i override a method that in the extension

Tags: flutter, dart

what I did:

```
extension BigDate on DateTime {
  String get locatedWeekDay {
    switch (weekday) {
      case DateTime.sunday:
        return "Sun";
      case DateTime.monday:
        return "Mon";
      case DateTime.tuesday:
        return "Tue";
      ......
      default:
        throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
class JapanDate extends DateTime {
  @override
  String get locatedWeekDay {
    switch (weekday) {
      case DateTime.sunday:
        return "日";
      case DateTime.monday:
        return "月";
      ......
      default:
        throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

now I just run this:

```
DateTime d = JapanDate(2022, 3, 2);
print(d.locatedWeekDay);
```

it returns me "Wed" oh, can you help me to fix it?

I tried: to add @override to the get method, add the import to the first line.

Comment: now I try extend the DateTime and use typedef to rename it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods are *static*; [they are *compile-time* syntactic sugar for an equivalent freestanding function](https://medium.com/dartlang/extension-methods-2d466cd8b308).  As such, they are wholly dependent on the static type of the variable (whether explicitly declared or inferred), which in your case is `DateTime`.  They cannot be overridden since overrides involve *runtime* polymorphism.

What you could do instead is:

1. Create a base class (or mixin) that provides the `locatedWeekDay` interface.
2. Make `JapanDate` derive from that interface.
3. Make your extension method check if `this` implements that interface, falling back to a default implementation if it's an ordinary `DateTime` object.

```dart
abstract class HasLocatedWeekDay {
  String get locatedWeekDay;
}

extension BigDate on DateTime {
  String get locatedWeekDay {
    // Type-promotion for `this` is not yet supported.
    // See: <https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1397>
    final self = this;
    if (self is HasLocatedWeekDay) {
      return self.locatedWeekDay;
    }

    switch (weekday) {
      case DateTime.sunday:
        return "Sun";
      case DateTime.monday:
        return "Mon";
      case DateTime.tuesday:
        return "Tue";
      ......
      default:
        throw Exception();
    }
  }
}

class JapanDate extends DateTime implements HasLocatedWeekDay {
  @override
  String get locatedWeekDay {
    switch (weekday) {
      case DateTime.sunday:
        return "日";
      case DateTime.monday:
        return "月";
      ......
      default:
        throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't cast it to `DateTime` leave it as `JapanDate` and the code above should work as you expect it to.

```
JapanDate d = JapanDate(2022, 3, 2);
print(d.locatedWeekDay);
```

Comment: but this is not what I wanted.

Comment: So what did you want?

Comment: I'd suggest just using ```var```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `locatedWeekDay` method on `DateTime`. Therefore, it can't be overridden, but you can create a custom class extending this or use an extension as you did for `BigDate`.

To create a custom class, you need to pass data to super class.

```dart
class JapanDate extends DateTime {
  JapanDate(int year,
      [int month = 1,
      int day = 1,
      int hour = 0,
      int minute = 0,
      int second = 0,
      int millisecond = 0,
      int microsecond = 0])
      : super(
            year,
            month = month,
            day = day,
            hour = hour,
            minute = minute,
            second = second,
            millisecond = millisecond,
            microsecond = microsecond);

  String get locatedWeekDay {
    switch (this.weekday) {
      case DateTime.sunday:
        return "日";
      case DateTime.monday:
        return "月";
      //....
      default:
        return "N";
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use `JapanDate` class with `locatedWeekDay`.

```dart
  JapanDate d = JapanDate(2022, 3, 7);

  print(d.locatedWeekDay); ///月
```

About `.weekday` on `DateTime`. It is defined as

```dart
 external int get weekday;
```

> External Functions
> An external function is a function whose body is provided separately from its
> declaration. An external function may be a top-level function (17), a method

You can follow this [What does external mean in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24929659/10157127)

Comment: Check about [External](https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf#External%20Functions)

Comment: I know what is external means (I think), I want to extend the locatedWeekDay get method on DateTime for English users.

Comment: You can test the answers on your question, hope some will answer. I thought you like to extend the class, and I've followed that way.